# Chrome extension: converting a localStorage value to boolean in content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, global-variables, content-script

I am currently converting one of my userscripts to a chrome extension. The only thing I am still stuck with is successfully storing the localStorage values in variables in my content script. I will give one example here, the other ones are similar but with other names.

```
var REMOVE_WARNINGS;

chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "REMOVE_WARNINGS"}, function(response) {
console.log(response.status);
REMOVE_WARNINGS = response.status == "true";
});
```

As you can see, I query the localStorage of my extension for the value that was assigned to "REMOVE_WARNINGS". I do that because further on in the content script, this variable gets checked to see whether it has to perform certain actions or not. The original value gets assigned in the localStorage through the options page by a HTML  option, either true or false, which happens without a problem. The value "true" (or "false") gets successfully returned to the content script's method and printed in the console, because I have checked it. What **DOESN'T** work is assigning the value to the global variable REMOVE_WARNINGS in my content script.

I have tried a few options, including `REMOVE_WARNINGS = response.status;`, `REMOVE_WARNINGS = response.status == "true";` and I have also tried to remove the console output line thinking that it might print destructively. None of these options seems to successfully store the boolean value "true" or "false" in the global variable, because the script does not perform the actions it should do.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? I'm completely lost at this point, especially since clearly reading the value is no problem. It's storing it in a global variable of the content script, that is the problem.

Cheers
Kenneth

Comment: If you're expecting the line of code after that `sendRequest()` block to have the updated value in your global variable, well, it probably won't, because that's an asynchronous operation.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. The whole piece of code is in fact one method call, the last parameter being a function to handle the answer. Clearly the printing in that function works fine (it prints the correct value to the console), so I would not know why the same value does not get assigned to the global variable.
Could you elaborate a bit further please?

Comment: My point is that there's a gap in control flow between the call to `sendRequest()` and the call to the callback function you pass in. The next line of code after the code you posted will happen **immediately** - and **before** the code in the callback runs.

Comment: Oh. I figured that the method call waited on itself for the answer to kick in. Apparently not. Would you happen to know how I can handle this? Obviously the script should wait for all values to kick in before processing the rest of the script.

Comment: Well I'm not super-familiar with extensions, but generally what you do in other callback-oriented JavaScript situations is to structure your code such that you do your work *inside* the callback function(s).

Comment: Embedding the method calls to do the work inside the response handler did not do the job either. I tried this:
`chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "REMOVE_WARNINGS"}, function(response) {
 if(response.status) doSomething();
});`

Comment: It would help tremendously if you would elaborate on what **exactly** you mean when you say it "doesn't work".  What precisely is leading you to conclude that your code cannot assign a  value to a variable? What is your evidence?

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I was doing something else wrong, my bad. What I meant with "doesn't work" was simply that the required piece of code was simply not executed successfully. I forgot to change a value somewhere which was silly, now it works!

Comment: Well I'm glad to help!  Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please correct me if I'm wrong but I think you're trying to do something like:

```
var REMOVE_WARNINGS;

chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "REMOVE_WARNINGS"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.status);
    REMOVE_WARNINGS = response.status == "true";
});
console.log(REMOVE_WARNINGS); //this console.log will fail? right?
```

Try to modify your code like this:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "REMOVE_WARNINGS"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.status);
    REMOVE_WARNINGS = response.status == "true";
    doSomething();
});

function doSomething() {
    console.log(REMOVE_WARNINGS); //this one should work
}
```

Comment: Thank you and @Pointy. Indeed, doing the stuff inside the chrome request call works like a charm!

Comment: It was a pleasure to help you :)